# Where can I find the proof of Seifert-van Kampen using generators and relations?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does anybody know any books or websites where I cand find the proof of Seifert- van Kampen theorem using generators and relators? I've been reading the proof in Kosniowski's algebraic topology, but I would like to have another versión, and if it is done for an arbitrary open cover (not just with two elements), much better. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: tom Dieck has a proof in Section 2.6 (pg. 45) of his book *Algebraic Topology*. I believe that May also has a proof in *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology*.